# Azure WebApp Restarts

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

We have an Azure webapp with a webjob that runs continuously processing data files.  Yesterday, it shut down and restarted four times which seemed to be a lot.  I realize in the cloud that things work differently than a fixed server but that just seemed to be excessive.  After looking at our usage, we were told that we needed to upgrade from an S1 to an S2 instance because our usage was excessive.  When I look at the graph though, I don't think our usage is that high.  I was specifically told that if memory usage is high (in our case 60%) or CPU usage spikes a lot to 100%, they will recycle the app as it will consider the job "stuck".  While our memory usage floats around 60%, our CPU usage tends to stay below 20% consistently.

Does anyone have any knowledge on the metrics that are used for webapps?  As I look at the graph, I don't think that our usage is that high and it certainly doesn't justify doubling the size.  Am I missing something here?

[image]

Comment: can you share your site name directly or indirectly?https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly  and what is the time range when you saw your site been restart 4 times?